# Scrape analysts data from yahoo finances with R

Tags: css, r, rvest

I simply want to get the numbers presented as reccomendation, current price and target price, situated at the right side of the analyst webpage of yahoo finances of any given stock. Ex: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MT/analysts?p=MT"

There is a tutorial to scrape websites here: http://zevross.com/blog/2015/05/19/scrape-website-data-with-the-new-r-package-rvest/ and i am following it. However, despite the css selectors and xpath, are apparently easy to get from firefox, then they don't seem to retrieve any data. Any idea why?

Here is the Code:

First, load the packages

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(ggmap)
library(leaflet)
library(RColorBrewer)
```

Then, parse the website

```
url<-read_html("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MT/analysts?p=MT")
```

Now, to pull out the values of current price, target price and reccomendation
one should find the name of the css selector by pressing f12 on the page (in firefox or google browsers), then clicking on the selector tool item, and then double clic on the desired number. Below on the screen, the number will appear and its respective css selector can be obtained by right clicking on it and copying it with the option "css selector".

```
selector_name<-"div.dot-label:nth-child(3) > span:nth-child(2)"
fnames<-html_nodes(x = url, css = selector_name) %>%
```

However, nothing comes, and using xpath istead of the css selector gives identical result

Thanks in advance,
Agus

Comment: What exactly do you want to scrape from this url? Because, definitely the xpath, div.dot-label:nth-child(3) > span:nth-child(2) does not yield any results. I ask you to clarify your question because, "current price, target price and reccomendation" do not exist on the url provided.

Comment: Thanks for you attention. At the right side of the website provided you can read "Reccomendation rating", I want the number right below that. Below those ratings, there are the "price targets" and I want to get the current and average price values.